# How is an href value accessed from an HTML div element using Python and Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How does one access a link from `HTML` divs?

Here is the `HTML` I am trying to scrape, I want to get the `href` value:

```
<div class="item-info-wrap">
<div class="news-feed_item-meta icon-font-before icon-espnplus-before"> <span class="timestamp">5d</span><span class="author">Field Yates</span> </div>
<h1> <a name="&amp;lpos=nfl:feed:5:news" href="/nfl/insider/story/_/id/31949666/six-preseason-nfl-trades-teams-make-imagining-deals-nick-foles-xavien-howard-more" class=" realStory" data-sport="nfl" data-mptype="story">
Six NFL trades we'd love to see in August: Here's where Foles could help, but it's not the Colts</a></h1>
<p>Nick Foles is running the third team in Chicago. Xavien Howard wants out of Miami. Let's project six logical deals.</p></div>
```

Here is the code I have been trying to use to access the `href` value:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
source = requests.get('https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/_/name/phi/philadelphia-eagles').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
for article in soup.find_all('div', class_='item-info-wrap'):
    headline = article.h1.a.text
    print(headline)
    summary = article.p.text
    print(summary)

    try:
        link_src = article.h1.a.href # Having difficulty getting href  value
        print(link_src)
        link = f'https://espn.com/{link_src}'

    except Exception as e:
        link = None

    print(link)
```

The output I am getting is *https://espn.com/None* for every ESPN article. Appreciate any help and feedback!

Answer (score 1):

If you change the code in line 12 like the code below, it should work.

```
link_src = article.h1.a["href"]
```

FYI https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This solved my issue and I appreciate the documentation.